# Nissan Torque specs

Tags: nissan, torque, sentra, torque-specification

I'm replacing the torque mounts on my 2014 Nissan Sentra S. I don't want to over tighten the bolts. So I am looking for torque specs for the torque strut mounts. (rear and front side) 18mm flanged hex bolts.. 2014 Nissan Sentra S.

Thank you.